# In Mac OS SWT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid

Tags: macos, cocoa, swt, illegalargumentexception

Getting this error when i am running my program in MAC, the same code is running fine with windows version.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setForeground(Control.java:3800)
```

**Enviornment**

java.version=1.6.0_65

java.vendor=Apple Inc.

BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US

** code **

```
gc. setForeground ( SWTResourceManager. getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK))
```

changed as below and tried

```
gc. setForeground( SWTResourceManager. getColor(0,0,0))
```

still getting the error

Any suggestion are appreciated

Comment: The stack trace is for a setForeground on a Control, the `gc` in your code suggests a GC - are you sure it is this line of code? The Control exception is because the Color has been disposed.

Comment: how to avoid from the Color getting disposed?

Comment: Need to see more of your code to get anywhere. Show more of the stack trace.